# PageSpeed Insights warns me about my AMP pages: "Remove duplicate modules in JavaScript bundles"

Tags: javascript, amp, google-pagespeed

I've checked the score of my AMP pages with Google PageSpeed Insight, and I received this message in red:
"Remove duplicate modules in JavaScript bundles"

This is the initial piece of code of my AMP pages. The fact is that I started with AMP pages several years ago, and now I'm not sure if I have to remove/update/add something.

```
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8" />     
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js">
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-experiment-0.1.js">
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js">
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-user-notification" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-user-notification-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-auto-ads" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-auto-ads-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-social-share" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-social-share-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-sidebar" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-sidebar-0.1.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-iframe" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-iframe-0.1.js"></script>
```